# artillary is not with SSH in ubuntu

Tags: ssh

I have installed Artillery in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I have started artillary and started that service with

```
service artillery start
```

while I am doing

```
netstat -nltp | grep LISTEN
```

why SSH port number not getting protection from the artillery ?

```
root@ubuntu:~# service artillery start
Starting Artillery...                             Ok
root@ubuntu:~# netstat -nltp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2657/perl       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1970/apache2    
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1377/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1377/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      636/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      998/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1377/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1749/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1377/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      636/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      998/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1377/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      1335/dovecot    
root@ubuntu:~#
```

may I know why and how I can give protection to the SSH port artillery ?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Oli something similar to http://thehackernews.com/2012/02/confusing-attackers-with-artillery-by.html & hi

Comment: What is the configuration contained in `/var/artillery`? Also, have you tried stopping the ssh server and starting artillery?

Comment: I have added ssh port number in the artillery configuration file.But still I can't able to do so